# Symfony 5 - Failed to start the session because headers have already been sent by "php://input" at line 1 in production

Tags: php, symfony

*** *EDIT - SOLVED* ***

In case it may help someone one day, the real cause was due to a malware on my server which was mining crypto through my php-fpm container.

If you want to check :

- Install htop to your server if it is ot already installed
- Look for you CPU utilisation if there is a program using all of it
- Remove it
- Secure your docker with networks and don't open port 9000

In my case, it was this one "devtmpfsi"

[kdevtmpfsi using the entire CPU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60151640/kdevtmpfsi-using-the-entire-cpu)

*** *END OF EDIT* ***

---

I know this error is old like the world but after searching for a solution for about three days on every different websites and topics I couldn't find anything that match my case.

So I hope so someone might help me.

### Context :

- I'm using the function fetch in JS to get my data
- I'm using docker in dev and prod environnement with nginx (1.10.3) and php-fpm (PHP: 7.4.12)
- Everything **work fine** in dev environnement
- It happen about few minutes / or after multiple refresh of the page, but everything work when I restart docker, and then, happen again

### Screenshots of the error

[First Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6Dlh.png)

[Second screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxwYQ.png)

### Code

**JS :**

```
const fetchSkinWithParameters = () => {
        fetch(platformUrl + '/api/skins', {
            method: "POST",
            body: JSON.stringify({
                currentIndex: containerPage1.dataset.currentindex,
                type: containerPage1.dataset.currenttype,
            })
        }).then((res) => {
            return res.json();
        }).then((data) => {
            data = data.data;
            name = data.name;
            totalSkin = data.totalSkin;
            id = data.id;

            skinSelectorPreview.dataset.id = id.toString();
            skinSelectorPreview.setAttribute('src', '/assets/images/skins/' + name);
        });
    }
```

**PHP (symfony 5):**

```
 /**
 * @Route("/api/skins"), name="choose_skin"
 */
public function chooseSkin(Request $request)
{
    $message = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);

    $type = $message['type'];

    $em = $this->getDoctrine();

    $skins = $em->getRepository(Skin::class)->findByType($type);

    $currentIndex = $message['currentIndex'];

    $data = [
        'id' => $skins[$currentIndex]->getId(),
        'name' => $skins[$currentIndex]->getName(),
        'totalSkin' => count($skins),
    ];

    $response = new Response();
    $response->setContent(json_encode([
        'data' => $data,
    ]));
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    $response->setStatusCode(200);

    return $response;
}
```

### Solutions I tried :

- Modifying my php.ini (output_buffering)
- Checking if I didn't have stupid spaces before any <?php
- And many little thing about session (starting a new one an so on)

This is my first in here post since I always found solutions over here, I'm quite annoyed right now :/

I'll provide any informations that you'll need / or I forgot to put in here if you ask

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

On your JS add `headers` this way:

```
fetch(platformUrl + '/api/skins', {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
         'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
         'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
          currentIndex: containerPage1.dataset.currentindex,
          type: containerPage1.dataset.currenttype,
    })
})
```